# H.264 RTP In-band parameter sets changing

Tags: h.264, rtp

I have an RFC 6184 stream that transmits SPS/PPS in its first packets. 
After around 5 seconds there is another SPS/PPS that changes the resolution of the stream.
My decoder handles this as expected nicely. Though my first question would be if it is legal according to the ISO standard.

My second concern is that when the stream is dumped to an ISO MP4, if it would cause any problem. As far as I know the AVC Configuration Record can handle multiple parameter sets.

Answer (score 1):

I would conciser It undefined behavior. If it works for you, that’s great, but it may not work forever or in all environments. MP4 can put SPS/PPS in with other frame data. So it’s at least possible to package. Again different players may or may not work correctly.